# use features to export products

Tags: commerce

i would like to use features module to export products. The commerce_features module gives a way to do the products types and other things but not product itself. It does not show up under content section or anywhere I can see. How to use features module to export products? How do you export products from one environment into another? Thank You for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Features will handle export and import of content types (a.k.a. products types, I think) but not nodes (which is what I think you mean by exporting "products".)  I have not used it myself, but I think that the [Node export](https://drupal.org/project/node_export) module is designed to do what you want.

Comment: Yeah, Features is designed to export configuration, not actual entities.